# SQL-Server: change data type IF it's a bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I am trying to change data type for a colyumn from bigint to int. I know how to do an alter statement and how to find which data type is currently assigned to it:

```
SELECT data_type
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table_Name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ColumnName'
```

However I can't figure out how to do it in an if statement. I only need to change the datatype IF it is currently bigint.

The table has no rows in it so moving data is not an issue at the moment.

I'd really appreciate the help, thanks in advance!

Comment: What output you get when you run the query you posted with your tablename and column name ?

Comment: Tip of today: Always have a script to create your database from scratch. Since you have no data, adjust that script and re-create the database.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the query returns one column "data_type" with one value bigint

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `IF` condition add the `BIGINT` filter in `Where` clause. Try something like this

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)=''

SET @sql = (SELECT 'alter table ' + Quotename(TABLE_NAME)
                   + ' alter column ' + Quotename(COLUMN_NAME)
                   + ' int ' + CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'yes' THEN ' NULL ' ELSE ' NOT NULL ' END
            FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'Table_Name'
                   AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ColumnName'
                   AND DATA_TYPE = 'bigint') 

Exec (@sql)
```

If the datatype is not `BIGINT` then there will be nothing to execute

Comment: I tried several different combinations of your answer, however I didn't seem to find the correct one, it didn't seem to work for me, however I figured the way to do it with an IF statement, don't know what happened before, but I was just stuck with it. @Prdp I was just wondering, is there some advantages/disadvantages in doing with the IF or the way you suggested? Thanks!